# Get the sum of a double / float in a list of a class for each matching object containing equal strings

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

My current code:

```
List<Float> totalAmounts = sources.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getAmount, Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream().sorted(entryComp).map(Map.Entry::getValue).limit(3).toList();
```

The idea, is that it adds up all of `Cause.getAmount()`, which is a `float` into a list of max 3 elements
The `Cause` class constructor looks like this, `Cause` has all getters and setters.

```
public Cause(String name, int time, float amount) {}
```

For example, the `sources` list would look like

```
new Cause("Name", 34, 15.53F);
new Cause("Name", 636, 2.12F);
new Cause("Name", 2345, 3.14F);
new Cause("Name", 568, 9F);
new Cause("OtherName", 10, 5.55F);
new Cause("OtherName", 5324, 0.27F);
new Cause("OtherName", 1, 6.21F);
new Cause("RealName", 921, 7.05F);
new Cause("RealName", 3899, 11.11F);
new Cause("RealName", 1782, 8.38F);
new Cause("BadName", 234, 1.01F);
new Cause("BadName", 581, 6.31F);
```

and the expected result of `totalAmounts` as the full `<K, V>` would be

```
(4, 29.79F)
(3, 12.03F)
(3, 26.54F)
```

(I am aware I am only pulling the `Entry::getValue` )
The *key* is the number of equal strings
The *value* is the sum of all objects with the equal strings' last constructor parameter (It must be either a double or float)
Here's my whole code.

```
List<Cause> sources = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

private String topThree() {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Long>> entryComparator = Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
    Comparator<Map.Entry<Float, Double>> entryComp = Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());

    List<String> most = sources.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().sorted(entryComparator).map(Map.Entry::getKey).limit(3).toList();

    List<Long> mostTimes = sources.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().sorted(entryComparator).map(Map.Entry::getValue).limit(3).toList();

    List<Float> total = sources.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getAmount, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream().sorted(entryComp).map(Map.Entry::getValue).limit(3).toList();

    for (int i = 0; i < most.size(); i++) {
        try {
            result.append((i+1) + ". " + most.get(i) + " " + mostTimes.get(i) + " " + total.get(i) + "\n");
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ignored) {}
    }
    return result.toString();
}

@Getter @Setter
private static final class Cause {
    private Source source;
    private String name;
    private float amount;
    private int tickRecordedOn;

    public Cause(Source source, String name, float amount, int tickRecordedOn) {
        this.source = source;
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.tickRecordedOn = tickRecordedOn;// Used for syncing, nothing else
    } 
}
```

The idea behind the `topThree` method is to return

```
(Cause Name) (Amount of times the Cause name is in the list) (The sum of the Cause amount)
```

Basically condensing the list of Cause into a single string that is Cause, just added up each value.

Comment: you should group by name and then add corresponding amount in map value, as per your expectation you key is count which can occur more than once which is not possible in map. map cant have duplicate key . 

Map<String, Double> result = causes.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName,
                        Collectors.summingDouble(Cause::getAmount)));

        System.out.println("Count of names and sum of float values:");
        result.forEach((name, sum) -> System.out.println(name + ": " + sum));
    }

Comment: Would sending my whole code help?
I know I kinda explained it poorly, but the code should speak for itself.

Comment: ya that will make some sense its not clear .  mention what output you are getting and what you want

Comment: The question is unclear, please explain clearly what you want to achieve and what goes wrong. First you talk about (and do) grouping and counting by the amount, then you talk about grouping by name and summing the amount. Which of those do you want to do? Both? Please explain.

Comment: Also, don't post your entire code, it just distracts from the problem. Condense it to a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What you have currently is enough as long you explain clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Chaosfire 
The goal is to group each entry in `sources` by Cause name, add up the total amount of Causes grouped, and get the sum of `amount` from each Cause that is grouped.

Comment: @Extent You were also talking about max 3 elements per group. How do you define max 3, if there are more? First three elements encountered, comparison by a property, something else?

Comment: @Chaosfire The group can have an arbitrary number of elements, The COMPRESSED group should be limited to the top 3 grouped elements.

Comment: @Extent The question still stands, how do you choose the top 3?

Comment: @Chaosfire I've done that already, except the last element, the float.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your two statements

```java
List<String> most = sources.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream().sorted(entryComparator).map(Map.Entry::getKey).limit(3).toList();

List<Long> mostTimes = sources.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream().sorted(entryComparator).map(Map.Entry::getValue).limit(3).toList();
```

perform the same (almost) operation two times, dropping the information needed by the other result in the `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` resp. `.map(Map.Entry::getValue)` step.

So, remove this `map` step and collect the information in a result containing all information, e.g.

```java
Map<String,Long> mostTimes = sources.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName, Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())).limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

This map will not be ordered but contain the top three elements.

Now, to integrate the missing sum of amounts, change `Collectors.counting()` to [`Collectors.summarizingDouble(Cause::getAmount)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#summarizingDouble(java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction)). Since this changes the result’s value from `Long` to `DoubleSummaryStatistics`, the comparator also needs to be changed:

```java
Map<String, DoubleSummaryStatistics> mostTimes = sources.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName,
            Collectors.summarizingDouble(Cause::getAmount)))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
            Comparator.comparingDouble(DoubleSummaryStatistics::getSum)))).limit(3)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Since the intended final result is a `String`, one option is to change the collector to create a `String` in the first place. This would also respect the order established by the `sorted` step:

```java
private String topThree() {
    return sources.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName,
            Collectors.summarizingDouble(Cause::getAmount)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
            Comparator.comparingDouble(DoubleSummaryStatistics::getSum)))).limit(3)
        .map(entry -> entry.getKey()
                      + " " + entry.getValue().getCount()
                      + " " + entry.getValue().getSum())
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}
```

This will produce

```
Name 4 29.78999972343445
RealName 3 26.539999961853027
OtherName 3 12.030000239610672
```

which might be an acceptable result if you can live without the preceding ranking number.

Otherwise, the solution will involve a bit more manual processing:

```java
private String topThree() {
    return sources.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Cause::getName,
            Collectors.summarizingDouble(Cause::getAmount)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new), list -> {
            list.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(
                Comparator.comparingDouble(DoubleSummaryStatistics::getSum)));
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for(int rank = 1, i = list.size()-1; i >= 0 && rank <= 3; rank++,i--) {
                result.append(rank).append(". ").append(list.get(i).getKey())
                    .append(" ").append(list.get(i).getValue().getCount())
                    .append(" ")
                    .append(list.get(i).getValue().getSum()).append("\n");
            }
            return result.toString();
        }));
}
```

This will produce

```
1. Name 4 29.78999972343445
2. RealName 3 26.539999961853027
3. OtherName 3 12.030000239610672
```

Since the `sorted` step implies buffering of all objects for sorting, typically in an array, I moved the sorting into the finisher function which has to process a list (wrapping an array) anyway.

It is possible to solve the task without collecting and sorting all elements, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30774023/2711488). However, such an optimization will only pay off if the number of groups is significantly larger than your limit, i.e. not in your example of selecting three out of four.